# MongoDB - Limit geometry data in geospatial $nearby

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, geospatial

I have the below document in a collection

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("589550ae930b4acade1e2157"),
"itemId" : "2",
"loc" : {
    "type" : "GeometryCollection",
    "geometries" : [
        {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                -121.9771985,
                37.5637936
            ],
            "address" : "Athy St"
        },
        {
            "type" : "Point",
            "coordinates" : [
                -121.9430202,
                37.3972994
            ],
            "address" : "River Side Ct"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am using the below query to find the item from the nearest location:

```
db.store.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [-121.9777269,37.5607686] },
            $maxDistance: 3.0 * 1609.34
          }
       }
   }
)
```

I am trying to restrict to fetch and display only the nearest matching address. Suppose if the queried location matches only River Side ct, I don't want to return Athy Street. This is geometry collection array. I tried to use projections but didn't work.

Can you please let me know how to restrict that? Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Maddy

Answer (score 1):

The MongoDB `$near` operation sorts by distance (nearest to farthest,
 as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/near/)), so all you will have to do is limit the results.

```
db.store.find(
   {
     loc:
       { $near :
          {
            $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [-121.9777269,37.5607686] },
            $maxDistance: 3.0 * 1609.34
          }
       }
   }
).limit(1)
```